# How do you access values passed to next() functions in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm using *Node* with *Express.js* to write a back-end for a project I'm working on.

`next()` functions are used in middleware to move to the next piece in the middleware chain, and finally onto the `app.VERB()` function. Where and how (further down the line) do I access this variable?

Example code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    User.findOne({
            'email': emailValue
        }, function (err, foundUser) {

            if (err) return next(err); 

            // Else do something
        }
    }); 
});
```

What has access to the `err` value passed to `next()`?

Comment: Does this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-expressjs

Comment: It's useful but doesn't answer the `next(var)` question. It's something I could use, but this seems to be built in functionality. I keep seeing `next(err)`. What has access to that variable?

Comment: If there's an error, the middleware stops processing. That's how you'd signal an error. It's not how you pass values.

Comment: As @StefanMoraru linked, a way to pass values along is to store them in the `req` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an error parameter into `next`, Express invokes whatever error middleware handler you've installed.  The error middleware function has four arguments, so you'd install your own handler as:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // handle the err from a previous middleware's next(err) call
});
```

You'd typically add this at the end of your middleware chain so that it handles all other middlewares' errors.

See [here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) for the Express documentation on this.

Comment: Would that also mean `app.get('/wherever', function (err, req, res, next) {...});` would work?

Comment: Okay. So what I was missing was this was purely for errors. I struggled to find anything on the Express site. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alexcoady Glad it helped.  I added a link the Express docs on this to the answer.