# How to pass a variable through routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var testVar = "Hello World";

var index = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/', index);
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(testVar);
});

module.exports(router);
```

How to pass the variable "testVar" in ./routes/index.js? Someone has an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can make a middleware function and set a variable from there

Comment: nha, Can you make an example code?

Comment: Something like that : `app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  req.myvar = "this is in my request now";
  next();
});`

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-expressjs

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a middleware like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var testVar = "Hello World";

var myMiddleWare = function (req, res, next) {
    req.testVar = testVar;

    next();
}

var index = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/', myMiddleWare, index);
```

The middleware is called for every request to the index.

The only difference to a normal route-function is the third parameter "next", which might be called to go to the next step (the index), or not called (in case an error happend or something else)

You can read more about middlewares here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `app.js`:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.testVar = testVar;
    next();
});
```

Then in `index.js` just get the `req` variable you set before:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.testVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable like below

```
   app.get('/user/:testVar', function (req,res,next) {
    });
```

Then retrieve the parameter with

```
req.params.testVar
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your purpose for doing this. But this is how you can send data to `./routes/index.js` without middleware and also get the router.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var testVar = null;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(testVar);
});

module.exports = function(testData){
    testVar = testData;
    return router;
}
```

app.js

```
var testVar = "Hello World";
var index = require('./routes/index')(testVar);
```