# Cannot pass params between middlewares

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I've searched for a way to pass data between middlewares in Express, and [I've found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-expressjs). Basically, the solution given is to create `req.somevariable = variable1;`.

As is told in the comments, req.somevariable throws undefined and the possible solution cosists on creating a previous middleware to initialize that variable.

Is there any simplier solution? I've also tried to do:

```
req.body.myVar = myVar;
```

But I still have the error about the var is `undefined`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it easily. Just store it *req* object.

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
  req.id = "123456789";
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  var id = req.id;
  // do your working
});
```

Comment: please share your full code, then community can found actual problem. 
my above method is 100% correct, It is copied from express official site.