# Error handling using middlewares

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning node from time to time. Have this question.

Middleware 1:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   db.load(function(err, session) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    ...
  });
 });
```

Middleware 2:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       next();
});
```

Route handler

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
});
```

Imagine middleware 1 calls `next(err)`. Now my question is:

- how do I understand in middleware 2 that error was issued from 1st middleware?

Comment: Also refer [__"passing variables to the next middleware using next() in expressjs"__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-expressjs)

Comment: This is not a duplicate... He's asking about errors. Not passing variables into the next function.

Comment: @meyer9 — Is there any way one could access passed value in next handler ?

Comment: If you throw an error, or next(err), you can access it by creating a middleware with the signature, `function(err, req, res, next) { console.log(err) }` and then using that in your app.

Comment: And if you wanted to continue addressing the error later down the middleware chain, you can add a next(err) onto that one.

Comment: @Rayon Doesn't seem like a dupe, I would reconsider the close vote if I were you.

Comment: @meyer9 How does it distinguish function(err, req, res, next) from function(req, res, next)?

Comment: @meyer9 Thanks I don't know what's wrong with people closing all questions as dupes

Comment: `(function(a){}).length = 1` and `(function(a, b){}).length = 2`.

Comment: I am curious about to be accepted answer of this question.. I have rolled back my close vote though....

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I posted this in answer form now here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42992187/2537322

Comment: @Bergi: We have a second incorrect duplicate vote cast here.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava How so ? "Error handling principles for Node.js + Express.js applications?" is perfect dupe!

Comment: @Rayon That link was not posted when I put this comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, middleware 2 will not be called until it has a function signature like :-

```
app.use(function(err,req, res, next){
  // your code
})
```

You can pass middleware name in error object you pass in middleware 1

```
next({err:err,name:'middleware1'})
```

And access name in middleware 2

```
console.log(err.name)
```

Comment: "First of all, middleware 2 will not be called until it has a function signature like" --> Why? How does it differentiate between two function signatures?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L65 , looping through the middleware stack, it checks for no. of the arguments, and above method is called from :- https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L135

Comment: Also , check out docs :- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: So using call next(error) --> it will jump to error handler middleware and skip other middlewares?

Comment: yes, you can handle the error inside that, kind of generic error handler for all middlewares in your app

Answer (score 0):

Error handling middleware can be accomplished by using 4 arguments in your middleware instead of 3. `function(err, req, res, next)`

For example, if you wanted to just print out the error, you could create a new middleware like this:

```
function logErrors (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  next(err)
}
app.use(logErrors)
```

They check the signature of a function by using the length property indicating the number of parameters. For example:

```
function func1(a) {}
function func2(a, b) {}

console.log(func1.length) # 1
console.log(func2.length) # 2
```

Once an express request errors out, it will skip any normal middleware to the next middleware that handles errors.

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Yes, but why will it jump to error handler middleware instead of running my second middleware? (check my code)

Comment: Once an express request errors out, it will skip any normal middleware to the next middleware that handles errors.