# Choosing which middleware to run based on request in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to know how to choose between two different middleware functions, depending on the request for the endpoint. It could look something like this:

```js
router.post("/findAvailableAgents", middleware1 || middleware2, (req, res) => {
  // endpoint body
})
```

Comment: how do you determine if middleware1 or middleware2 needs to be used?

Comment: can you code middleware 3 to use either?

Comment: I determine if middleware1 or middleware2 based on tokens sent with the request. If the tokens are valid, the request is allowed to go through else reject request.

Comment: @Moak, How would you suggest I do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use another *middleware* which decides whether to choose *middleware1* or *middleware2*

```
const decideMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    if(condition) {
        return middleware1(req, res,next)
    } else {
        return middleware2(req, res,next)
    }
}
```

And use it in your code

```
router.post("/findAvailableAgents", decideMiddleware, (req, res))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is two ways of achieve optional middleware behaviour:

1) Create another middleware, that checks condition and then passes all the parameters into the desired middleware. Example:

```
const middlewareStrategy = (req,res,next) => {
    if(req.body.token1){
        return middleware1(req,res,next);
    }
    return middleware2(req,res,next);
};

router.post("/findAvailableAgents", middlewareStrategy, handler);
```

2) Make middleware logic execution in a condition-driven manner. Example:

```
const middleware1 = (req,res,next) => {
    if(req.body.token){
        // execute some logic, then
        return next();
    }
    // skip this middleware
    next();
};

router.post("/findAvailableAgents", middleware1, middleware2, handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can add multiple middleware using a below peice of code

```js
app.get('/',[middleware.requireAuthentication,middleware.logger], function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello!');
});
```

Comment: It's not working. Perhaps I should be clearer with my question. I need to use either middlewares to process requests.

Comment: Here's the idea. 
app.get('/',middleware1,middleware2, function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello!');
});
We have two middlewares. Now, pass the result from middleware 1 to middleware 2.
Refernce : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-express-js @DaveKalu

Comment: No, I don't need to pass the request to the next middleware. I need to reject or resolve the request if the request is valid. That is why I thought an "or" operator would work.