# Why is this exported function in NodeJS not working as I want it to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables, module.exports

I am trying to get this code below run as middleware from an exported function.

```
fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => {
scraperDate = stats.mtime.toUTCString();
});
```

I have

```
let scraperDate = "";
```

in top of my routes file. Im trying to do this:

```
router.get("/", myFunctions.scraperDateFunction, function (req, res) {
res.render("my_view", {scraped: scraped, scraperDate: scraperDate});
});
```

When I just run the scraperDate code as it is, above the route, it works. When I put it in my functions.js file to module.exports it wont write to the scraperDate variable.

I am probably missing something obvious here, but I have tried to get this to work for the better part of two days now. This is my module.exports for the function:

```
module.exports = {
    scraperDateFunction: function(){
        fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => {
            scraperDate = stats.mtime.toUTCString();
        });
    }
}
```

*** Edit ***

I have now tried this

```
getScrapeDate: function(req, res, next){
    fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => {
        scraperDate = stats.mtime.toUTCString();
        console.log(err)
        console.log(stats)  
        return next;        
    });
}
```

which prints the  `stats`  as expected to console withour any errors. It is likely something with the scope. How would I pass the result of  `stats.mtime.toUTCString();`  to the  `scraperDate`  variable in the route?

*** Edit 2 ***

I now have this in my functions file

```
    getScrapeDate: function(req, res, next){
    fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
            next (err);
        } else {
            res.locals.scraperDate = stats.mtime.toUTCString()
        }

    });
}
```

and this in my routes file as suggested but it does not load my view

```
router.get("/", myFunctions.getScrapeDate, function (req, res) {
    let {scraperDate} = res.locals;
    res.render("my_view", {scraped: scraped, scraperDate: 
    scraperDate});
});
```

scraped is declared in the top of the routes file.

*** Final Edit ***

This is a setup that is now working

```
router.get("/", myFunctions.getScrapeDate, function (req, res) {
    let {scraperDate} = res.locals;
    res.render("my_view", {scraped, scraperDate});
 });
```

and

```
    getScrapeDate: function(req, res, next){
    fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
            next (err);
        } else {
            res.locals.scraperDate = stats.mtime.toUTCString();
            next();
        }                   
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add `console.log(err)` in your `fs.stat` callback?

Comment: A middleware needs to take a `next` callback and call it - especially if it is asynchronous

Comment: Scopes are not shared between modules, a defined variable in one is not visible in another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not define `scraperDate` at the top of your functions module, and do not attempt to import it into your routes module either. At best this is code-smell, and at worst you end up inadvertently leaking information between separate request-response cycles that should *not* be shared.

What you should do is follow [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38355597/1541563) to pass data between middleware using [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals):

In your routes file:

```
router.get('/', myFunctions.scraperDateFunction, (req, res) => {
  const { scraperDate } = res.locals;
  // the following is shorthand in ES2015 syntax for
  // { scraped: scraped, scraperDate: scraperDate }
  res.render('my_view', { scraped, scraperDate });
});
```

And in your functions file:

```
module.exports = {
  scraperDateFunction (req, res, next) {
    fs.stat('./tmp/my_data.json', (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.locals.scraperDate = stats.mtime.toUTCString();
        next();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Again, do not try to define and export a top-level `scraperDate` variable in your functions file, this is a cleaner approach to passing data between your middleware in express.

Comment: @75martin the call to `next()` in the `else` is _not optional_. Re-read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `scraperDate` variable inside the `scraperDateFunction` in your module is not exported, since scopes are not shared between different modules. This would break the entire purpose of modules.

Check the [reference docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: yes, Patrick Evans mentioned this. how do I access the stats part of the function?

Comment: fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => {
            return stats.mtime.toUTCString();
        });

Comment: tried fs.stat("./tmp/my_data.json", (err, stats) => { return stats.mtime.toUTCString()}); but it does not seem to pass on the date...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts im dabbling with it right now... i recall using res.locals at some other place, thanks for the suggestion! ill update

Comment: @75martin This is what the `res.locals` object is for. Setting variables directly on the request object is not supported or documented. `res.locals` is guaranteed to hold state over the life of a request.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz yes, I don't know why someone downvoted his first response.. :D