# multer: how to pass variables to next handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, middleware, multer

I'm using `multer` to upload images. The following is my multer configuration:

```js
import multer from "multer";
import * as mime from "mime-types";
import path from "path";

export const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req: any, file, cb) {
    const name = path.parse(file.originalname).name + "_" + Date.now();
    const extension = mime.extension(file.mimetype);
    const filename = `${name}.${extension}`;
    /**
    req.fileInfo = {
      filename,
      name,
      extension
    } */
    cb(null, filename);
  },
});
export const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

I want to get `fileInfo` object in next handler.

```js
import { upload } from "src/middlewares/imageUpload";

router.post('/imageUpload', upload.single("upload"), async (req, res) => {

//
const filename = req.fileInfo.filename;

});
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-express-js), `res.local` is the correct place to store variables between middleware and handlers.

But multer diskStorage configuration does not accept `res` parameter. I tried to store `fileInfo` object in `req` but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't(req.fileInfo is undefined for some routes, although the code is exactly the same).

How can I pass `fileInfo` to next handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multer` middleware automatically sets the property named `file` on `req` object which contains the information about the uploaded file and can be accessed in the next middleware, so you don't need to set it your self.

If you still want to do that, you can attach `fileInfo` object to `req` object but it will only be available in next handlers where `multer` middleware is one of the middlewares in the pipeline. So `req.fileInfo` will be undefined for routes for which request doesn't goes through `multer` middleware.

You can make every request pass through the `multer` middleware but if that request doesn't contains any file that should be uploaded, `req.fileInfo` will be undefined because no file was uploaded by `multer`.

Comment: So, in other words,  if `req.fileInfo` is undefined, that means multer didn't upload any files?

Comment: `req.fileInfo` will contain the info about the uploaded file, right? So if multer hasn't uploaded any file, what will `req.fileInfo` contain? In short, code in your multer configuration will execute only if there's a file to be uploaded

Comment: I passed an array to form data in frontend. Changed it to file object and it worked. Thanks!