# Pass user object to specific route in express

Tags: node.js, express, web-development-server

I want to send user object to specific route before redirecting to that route .
I have tried this solution [res.locals.var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875292/passing-variables-to-the-next-middleware-using-next-in-express-js) but its returning undefined .

I am redirecting user from `signup` route to `lounge` route .

Here is the code - https://pastecord.com/mecyheducu.js
I am stuck at this for the whole day now

Answer (score 0):

You can use several ways:

- **Send it in the URL**
  you cannot directly pass a complete JavaScript object in the URL. However, you can
  serialize the object into a format that can be sent as a query parameter,
  such as JSON or URL encoding.

Here's an example of how you can serialize a JavaScript object into JSON and
send it as a query parameter during a redirect:

```
app.get('/redirect', function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    name: 'Mohammed',
    age: 25,
  };

  var serializedData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
  res.redirect('/next-route?data=' + serializedData);
});

app.get('/next-route', function(req, res) {
   var serializedData = req.query.data;
   var data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(serializedData));
   // Use the data as needed
   res.send(data);
});
```

- **Send it in session**
  You need to use session middleware such as `express-session`, you can store the complete JavaScript object in a session variable and access it in the redirected request. Here's an example:

  ```
  app.get('/redirect', function(req, res) {
     var data = {
       name: 'Mohammed',
       age: 25,
     };

     req.session.myData = data;
     res.redirect('/next-route');
   });

   app.get('/next-route', function(req, res) {
     var data = req.session.myData;
     // Use the data as needed
     res.send(data);
   });
  ```

Make sure you have set up the session middleware correctly before using this approach. You need to configure and initialize the session middleware in your Express application. Here's a basic example:

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'your-secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```